# Python Regex split string into 5 pieces

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I'm playing around with Python, and i have run into a problem.
I have a large data file where each string is structured like this:

```
"id";"userid";"userstat";"message";"2013-10-19 06:33:20 (date)"
```

I need to split each line into 5 pieces, semicolon being the delimiter. But at the same time within the quotations.

It's hard to explain, so i hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: What form do you need the end product to be in? An array?

Answer (score 4):

That format looks a lot like `ssv`: semicolon-separated valued (like "csv", but semicolons instead of commas).  We can use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to handle this:

```
import csv

with open("yourfile.txt", "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

produces

```
['id', 'userid', 'userstat', 'message', '2013-10-19 06:33:20 (date)']
```

One advantage of this method is that it will correctly handle the case of semicolons within the quoted data automatically.

Comment: You can also parse plain strings: `reader = csv.reader(['"id";"userid";"userstat";"message";"2013-10-19 06:33:20 (date)"'], delimiter=';')`. Also, note that `csv` library does not play nicely with `unicode`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), no need of regex:

```
>>> strs = '"id";"userid";"userstat";"message";"2013-10-19 06:33:20 (date)"'
>>> strs.split(';')
['"id"', '"userid"', '"userstat"', '"message"', '"2013-10-19 06:33:20 (date)"']
```

If you don't want the double quotes as well, then:

```
>>> [x.strip('"') for x in strs.split(';')]
['id', 'userid', 'userstat', 'message', '2013-10-19 06:33:20 (date)']
```

Comment: So doing it this way would mean i'd be able to select each part like this: x[0] for the id,x[1] for the userid, and so on? i need each part to be manageable.

Comment: @BoinQ Yes, you can also assign the list items to variables using sequence unpacking: `idx, userid, stat, msg, dt = strs.split(';')`. BTW go for DSM's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19500522/846892), it is better than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can split by `";"` in you case, also consider using of regexp, like `^("[^"]+");("[^"]+");("[^"]+");("[^"]+");("[^"]+")$`

Comment: consider possibility to have `;` in message, and then use regexp